# Как вытащить tick из QTimer?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qtimer

У меня есть в коде `QTimer`, мне нужно вытащить из него `tick`, что бы в последующие разы можно было использовать `tick` как `int` выражение.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Что такое для Вас Tick, зачем его вытаскивать и как Вы хотите это использовать?

Comment: К примеру мне нужно поставить условие, если таймер дошёл до 10 tick (можно ms, разницы нет). Tick - мера времени, в секунде её содержится 20, обычно такая мера используется во многих играх, но можно использовать и обычные мили секунды, просто я думал, что легче вывести тики

Comment: Чем Вам сигнал таймаут не подходит?

Comment: Вопрос в том как его использовать, мне не принципиально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схематично:

```
class TickExample:

  def __init__(self):
    self.timer = QTimer()
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timeout)

    # для хранения предыдущего/текущего значения отсчета/среза времени
    self.previous = QDateTime.currentMSecsSinceEpoch()

    self.timer.start()    


  def timeout(self):
    current = QDateTime.currentMSecsSinceEpoch()
    print(f"tick is {current - self.previous}")

    # Сохраняем текущее значение для следующего раза
    self.previous = current
```

Comment: да, этот ответ подходит мне, но возможно ли как то все время обновлять этот таймер?

Comment: @TFader обновлять его шаг срабатывания?

Comment: я использовал ваш пример, но при установлении условия на Ваш таймер, у меня не изменял я итог, то есть я начал действие, в действии условие, если таймер будет делиться на 2 без остатка, то выполнять другое действие, потом возвращаться к предыдущему, если же с остатком, то продолжается, но у меня всегда продолжается